# opening a prism module on new window on a registered region

Tags: wpf, prism-4

I have an application with various modules.

I have divided my main shell (xaml) into different regions and now I can load modules on those regions.

But I have requirement where in on click of some button I have to open a new window and then a new module will load on the new window.

I created a new window and I am opening that window , but the window is having a region which the RegionManager of main application does not recognize.

How do I load a  module on a region which is not on main window but on child window ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you have a small working sample code that would be great. Otherwise, check out this sample from Microsoft. 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Child-Window-with-MVVM-f8e32d3e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a quick sample solution for your problem in the following **SkyDrive** public folder as "*RegionInChildWindowWithNavigation*":

- [RegionInChildWindowWithNavigation](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=7890102B5B8BC928&id=7890102B5B8BC928!103)

Based on my understanding, the problem you mentioned would be related on setting the `RegionManager` property on the ***ChildWindow*** View that cause the defined `ModalWindowRegion` be reachable from the `RegionManager`. Below is the `ModalDialog` ***ChildWindow*** view constructor from the aforemention sample. Notice that it also adds an event handler to properly remove all the views in the ***ChildWindow*** when closed.

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public ModalDialog(IRegionManager rm)
{
     this.rm = rm;
     this.SetValue(RegionManager.RegionManagerProperty, rm);
     InitializeComponent();
     this.Closed += new EventHandler(WindowsView_Closed);
}

void WindowsView_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      while (rm.Regions["ModalWindowRegion"].Views.Count() > 0)
      {
           rm.Regions["ModalWindowRegion"].Remove(rm.Regions["ModalWindowRegion"].Views.FirstOrDefault());
      }
}
```

Then, you would just need to `RequestNavigate()` to the specified **Region** which is defined in the ***ChildWindow*** view from the `RegionManager` as follows:

```
 ModalDialogWindow.Show();
 rm.RequestNavigate("ModalWindowRegion", new Uri("HelloWorldView", UriKind.Relative));
```

In addition, you may find useful the following CodePlex threads:

- [Define Region(s) in Childwindows using Prism + MVVM](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/281194)
- [Display Child window WPF](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/428995)

I hope this helps.

Comment: RegionInChildWindowWithNavigation link is not available :( is there other source?